# Relationships in Entity Framework Code First

Tags: c#, entity-framework, foreign-keys, code-first

yesterday I created database in Management Studio and now I want to create it in program using EF Code First.

Here is link to my database: http://s11.postimg.org/6sv6cucgj/1462037_646961388683482_1557326399_n.jpg

And what I did:

```
public class GameModel
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
    public string TotalTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime RouteStartTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime RouteEndTime { get; set; }
    public int MaxPlayersPerTeam { get; set; }

    public int CityId { get; set; }
    public int CreatorId { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("Id")]
    [ForeignKey("CreatorId")]
    //public int TeamId { get; set; }
    //[ForeignKey("TeamId")]

    public virtual UserModel Creator { get; set; }
    public virtual CityModel City { get; set; }
    //public virtual TeamModel WinnerTeam { get; set; }


}
public class RegionModel
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<CityModel> Cities { get; set; }
}
public class CityModel
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int RegionId { get; set; }

    public virtual RegionModel Region { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UserModel> Users { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<GameModel> Games { get; set; }
}
public class UserModel
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Login { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public DateTime RegistrationDate { get; set; }
    public string FacebookId { get; set; }

    public int CityId { get; set; }

    public virtual CityModel City { get; set; }

    public virtual IEnumerable<GameModel> Games { get; set; }
}
```

For now I wanted to create 4 tables but I have some problems... I want to make CreatorId in GameModel, but it doesn't work... When i wrote UserId instead of CreatorId it was working ( without [InverseProperty("Id")] and [ForeignKey("CreatorId")]).

This is what i get:

> The view 'The property 'Id' cannot be configured as a navigation property. The property must be a valid entity type and the property should have a non-abstract getter and setter. For collection properties the type must implement ICollection where T is a valid entity type.' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations.

edit:
I changed it like this:

```
    public int CityId { get; set; }
    public int CreatorId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CityId")]
    public virtual CityModel City { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CreatorId")]
    public virtual UserModel Creator { get; set; }
```

And there is another problem.

> The view 'Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.UserModels_dbo.CityModels_CityId' on table 'UserModels' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
>   Could not create constraint. See previous errors.' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations.

And I have no idea how to solve it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `InversePropertyAttribute` specifies, which *navigation property* should be used for that relation.

A navigation property must be of an entity type (the types declared in your model, `GameModel` for example) or some type implementing `ICollection<T>`, where `T` has to be an entity type. `UserModel.Id` is an `int`, which clearly doesn't satisfy that condition.

So, the inverse property of `GameModel.Creator` could be `UserModel.Games` if you changed the type to `ICollection<GameModel>`, or had to be left unspecified. If you don't specify an inverse property, EF will try to work everything out on its own (in this case it would properly recognize `GameModel.Creator` as a navigation property, but `UserModel.Games` would most likely throw an exception, as it is neither an entity type, nor does it implement `ICollection<T>` with `T` being an entity type, nor is it a primitive type from a database point of view). However, EF's work-everything-out-by-itself-magic doesn't cope too well with multiple relations between the same entity types, which is when the `InversePropertyAttribute` is needed.

A quick example that demonstrates the problem:

```
class SomePrettyImportantStuff {
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public int OtherId1 { get; set; }

    public int OtherId2 { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("OtherId1")]
    public virtual OtherImportantStuff Nav1 { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("OtherId2")]
    public virtual OtherImportantStuff Nav2 { get; set; }
}

class OtherImportantStuff {
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<SomePrettyImportantStuff> SoldStuff { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<SomePrettyImportantStuff> BoughtStuff { get; set; }
}
```

Here, EF knows that it has to generate 2 FKs from `SomePrettyImportantStuff` to `OtherImportantStuff` with the names `Id1` and `Id2`, but it has no way to tell which of the IDs refers to the entity where it was sold from and which is the one it was bought from.

**Edit: How to fix the cyclic reference problem**

To fix that problem, your context class should override `OnModelCreating` and configure the foreign keys which shouldn't cascade on delete accordingly, like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Entity<CityModel>().HasMany(c => c.Users).WithRequired(u => u.City)
           .HasForeignKey(u => u.CityId).WillCascadeOnDelete(value: false);

    // Add other non-cascading FK declarations here

    base.OnModelCreating(builder);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I edited my post cause I have another problem. Please have a look at it