# How to map the relationship between these 2 generated classes?

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I used to EF Code First From Database to generate classes based on an existing database. I need to map the relationship between these 2 classes.I suspect I have to set a foreign key but don't what to set the foreign key too.

```
Partial Public Class be_Posts
    <Key>
    Public Property PostRowID As Integer
    Public Property BlogID As Guid
    Public Property PostID As Guid
    <StringLength(255)>
    Public Property Title As String
    Public Property Description As String
    Public Property PostContent As String
    Public Property DateCreated As Date?
    Public Property DateModified As Date?
    <StringLength(50)>
    Public Property Author As String
    Public Property IsPublished As Boolean?
    Public Property IsCommentEnabled As Boolean?
    Public Property Raters As Integer?
    Public Property Rating As Single?
    <StringLength(255)>
    Public Property Slug As String
    Public Property IsDeleted As Boolean
End Class



Partial Public Class be_PostTag
    <Key>
    Public Property PostTagID As Integer
    Public Property BlogID As Guid
    Public Property PostID As Guid
    Public Property PostRowID As Integer
    <StringLength(50)>
    Public Property Tag As String
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems straight forward, but i may be missing something.  haven't coded in VB in a while so forgive any typos.

You'll want to add a Foreign Key relationship on the PostRowID values on your two tables.

I believe it should look something like this when you're done.

```
Partial Public Class be_Posts
    <Key>
    Public Property PostRowID As Integer
    Public Property BlogID As Guid
    Public Property PostID As Guid
    <StringLength(255)>
    Public Property Title As String
    Public Property Description As String
    Public Property PostContent As String
    Public Property DateCreated As Date?
    Public Property DateModified As Date?
    <StringLength(50)>
    Public Property Author As String
    Public Property IsPublished As Boolean?
    Public Property IsCommentEnabled As Boolean?
    Public Property Raters As Integer?
    Public Property Rating As Single?
    <StringLength(255)>
    Public Property Slug As String
    Public Property IsDeleted As Boolean
End Class



Partial Public Class be_PostTag
    <Key>
    Public Property PostTagID As Integer
    Public Property BlogID As Guid
    Public Property PostID As Guid
    Public Property PostRowID As Integer
    <StringLength(50)>
    Public Property Tag As String
    <ForeignKey("PostRowID")>
    Public Property PostRow As be_Posts
End Class
```

Here is an article that references a simple example of defining this FK relationship with Code First, the examples are in C# but should translate fairly well.

Comment: thank you for the answer. It did not work however. I added <ForeignKey("PostRowID")>Public Property PostRow As be_Posts to be_PostTag and added <ForeignKey("PostRowID")> to PostRowID in be_Posts. That then throw the error The property cannot configured as a navigation property. The property must be a valid entity type.

Comment: @AshokPadmanabhan Here is an SO article with a similar issue, the answer on it, provides good information and examples, can you see if those examples provide an answer for your new issue.  again sorry the examples are in C#. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20202578/relationships-in-entity-framework-code-first